# Website crashing on mobile browsers but loads on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I'm working on a slider for a website, and the way I have it set up is that there is basically a large stack of images where one slides off the page and the one below it becomes visible (imagine a deck of cards with an image on each card where the goal is to slide all of the cards off, but then slide them all back once you've reached the bottom, and when you slide them back, they're all in the same order you started in).

```
.background1 {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0, 0.45), rgba(0,0,0, 0.45)), url("../img/headerimg1.jpg");
background-size: 110%;
background-position: -25px 0px;
z-index: 8; }

.background2 {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0, 0.45), rgba(0,0,0, 0.45)), url("../img/headerimg2.jpg");
background-size: 110%;
background-position: -25px 0px;
z-index: 7; }
```

This is the CSS for each background card

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="background1"></div>
<div class="background2"></div>
<div class="background3"></div>
<div class="background4"></div>
<div class="background5"></div>
<div class="background6"></div>
<div class="background7"></div>
<div class="background8"></div>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var base = 12.5;
var percent = 100;
var background = 1;
$(".heading").animate({
    background: "#000"
}, 200);
setInterval(function() {
    if (base !== 100) {
        $(".slider-active").animate({
            left: base + "%"
        }, 500);
        base = base + 12.5;
        $(".background" + background).animate({
            left: "200%",
        }, 1000);
        background = (base / 12.5);
    }
    else {
        $(".slider-active").animate({
            left: "0%"
        }, 500);
        base = 12.5;
        $(".background1, .background2, .background3, .background4, .background5, .background6, .background7, .background8").animate({
            left: "0%"
        }, 1000);
        background = 1;
    } // end of if/else statement }, 5000); //end of interval function for slider }); //end of ready function
```

From what I've deciphered online, the issue is related to memory on the device, and that the mobile devices can't handle that many CSS items at once. I need suggestions on what to do with this, and how to handle this issue.

Comment: `can't handle that many CSS items at once`, 8 divs, with 10 css properties is not going to trouble any mobile device

Comment: Try a lower resolution image first. When I ran into crashing scenarios, usually the sheer amount of pixels was the problem. Remember: in graphics memory, compression is irrelevant. In graphics memory, all your images are decoded.

Comment: quick back-of-the-envelope-calculation: 8 backgrounds in Full HD (guessing, here!) 8 Backgrounds * 1920 * 1080 * 4 Bytes (32 bits per pixel) => ~64 Megabytes of graphics card ram. Maybe even more, some engines need to reserve powers of two (which would be 2048x2048pixels).

Comment: Most of the images are around 4K resolution, some higher